# Why do I get java.lang.OutOfMemoryError and pthread_create failed after a few days?

Tags: java, kotlin, kubernetes, jvm, pthreads

I know, the question sounds vague, but I'm trying to understand and solve this issue for some time already, i.e., without simply auto-restarting the pod (the application is running in K8s) regularly.

After a few days of the (Kotlin, Spring Boot) application running, I suddenly get a lot of these two:

- `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached`
- `Failed to start thread - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 256k, guardsize: 0k, detached.`

Monitoring screenshots:

- K8s pod resources: https://i.stack.imgur.com/McheM.png

  - Memory is not exhausted. But I've also tried with much larger amounts of RAM, e.g., 24 GB, and still had the same problem.
- JVM (Actuator) Metrics: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRPkl.png

  - Hovering the file-descriptors graph helps clarify the legend: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbrci.png
  - Neither the max number of threads is reached, nor the max number of file descriptors

Additional information:

- `ulimit -n`: `1048576`
- `ulimit -u`: `unlimited`
- `cat /proc/[...]/limits` (using my process ID): gist.github.com/Dobiasd/c6e38668b36f8eb97ff69e15a45cf635
- `cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max` gives `2060488`
- `/etc/security/limits.conf` is empty (only `#`-commented lines)
- `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -i thread` also does not look suspicious: https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/01623e9066889c8fd059bd387a15fafa
- Stack size (per thread) reduced to 256K (`-Xss256K`, default would be 1M).
- Thread dump (using `jcmd`) from a healthy pod, i.e., before the problem occurs, with already ~ 2k threads: gist.github.com/Dobiasd/391488295e6ffd05ecc5134450cd723d - Most of them are daemon threads from ThreadPoolExecutors, waiting for work. I assume it's the Google-cloud libraries (used for the BigQuery inserts) that spin those up. The jump to more threads later likely happens, because on some error condition, I'm re-instantiating the WriteStreams / JsonStreamWriters. Still, that should be ok. After some time, the old instances should be garbage collected and the threads die. So the 6 k threads should only exist temporarily (if things would work). And yes, of course, there might be ways to avoid this, but 6k threads still should not be a problem according to the existing limits.

Any ideas on what could be the cause and/or how to fix it?

---

Update 2022-06-01: I've now implemented a solution with fewer threads, also avoiding the big jump from ~2k threads to ~6k threads, visible in the Actuator graph above. This workaround helps me fix my problem, but my curiosity about why ~6k threads are too many in the first place of course persists. ;)

Comment: Do you intend to have 6K threads?

Comment: @tgdavies I'm consuming from ~ 300 Kafka topics (one consumer, thus thread, each), with ~ 400 different event types. Each event type is written into a separate BigQuery table, so I have at least 400 .`WriteStream`s and `JsonStreamWriter`s (both from `com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1`). I don't know how they handle threads internally. So while this might not sum up to 6000, the order of magnitude might fit.

Comment: The image you posted shows 6.1K threads. I'd take a thread dump and see whether there are any unexpected threads.

Comment: Also worth considering whether you expected the sudden jump from 2K to 6K

Comment: @tgdavies Ok, I'll try to do so, thanks. But assuming the 6k threads need to be there, do you have an idea why should it fail to create more threads when the limits for mem, threads, and file descriptors are far from being reached?

Comment: I've taken a thread dump (using `jcmd`) from a healthy pod (output: https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/391488295e6ffd05ecc5134450cd723d), i.e., before the problem occurs, with already ~ 2k threads. Most of them are daemon threads from `ThreadPoolExecutor`s, waiting for work. I assume it's the Google-cloud libraries (used for the BigQuery inserts) that spin those up. The jump to more threads later likely happens, because on some error condition, I'm re-instantiating the `WriteStream`s / `JsonStreamWriter`s. Still, that should be ok ...

Comment: It might be [OK](https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/s7qMSKpeavBerH1LCyFPIkNrW4k=/0x0:900x500/1400x1050/filters:focal(378x178:522x322):format(jpeg)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/49493993/this-is-fine.0.jpg). If you have error handling which creates thousands of new threads without ensuring that the old ones are stopped, you are asking for trouble.

Comment: Hehe (at the OK link). :D After some time, the old instances should be garbage collected and the threads die. So the 6 k threads should only exist temporarily (if things would work). And yes, of course, there might be ways to avoid this, but 6k threads still should not be a problem according to the existing limits. So I want to actually understand why they is a problem, not just somehow avoid the problem without understanding it. :)

Comment: Can you create a test environment where you can reproduce this issue in minutes rather than days?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I can try. :)

Comment: Thanks for the additional insights. While the large number of threads is suspicious and there's probably a deeper problem why you have so many I don't see an immediate problem why it would fail to create more threads, especially if you tried it with 24 GB ram. Perhaps @apangin can give you more insights?

Comment: After doing so more research I found this JDK issue and I'm wondering if perhaps it could be a subtle race condition? https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8268605 ->  (Christian Haeubl) found that a likely cause for this is one thread is calling execve() and the other about the same time is calling pthread_create(). In such case, pthread_create() can return EAGAIN "just because there is a concurrent execve()".

Comment: @JurajMartinka, it seems unlikely that that issue is related to your thread explosion, because a successful call to `execve` replaces the entire process image of the calling process (all threads) with a new one.  Moreover, it follows that semantically correct `execve` usage usually demands that the process (self-)terminate if a call to `execve` fails.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - it's not my "thread explosion", I was just commenting about what I found in JDK bugs database that could be related to OP's problem. I can imagine that one would not expect this to happen with `execve` yet the reality seems to be different from that expecation.

Answer (score 0):

While `cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max` is showing 2M threads allowed system wide, there may also be user level limits. On my WSL2 Linux I have:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
127953
$ ulimit -u
63976
```

In practice this simple test program manages to create 31k threads:

```
public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
                try {
                    new Thread(() -> {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(60000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }).start();
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

That's fewer than we expect given the `ulimit -u` result.

To start with you should check your `ulimit -u` in the container.

Comment: Thanks! `ulimit -u` prints `unlimited` in my pods.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm reading your graphs properly but here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRPkl.png
The "File Descriptors" graph shows "Max: 1.0 Mil Current: 1.0 Mil"
So it seems like you are hitting the max number of open files limit.

It's worth checking the limits on the command line via `ulimit -n`. You can also check the process limit `cat /proc/$(pgrep java)/limits`.

Comment: The legend of the graphs is confusing, yes. But hovering over it with the mouse cursor helps clarify (https://i.imgur.com/wBdu5RE.png). So I think the file descriptors are not exhausted. `ulimit -n` gives `1048576`. In `/proc/` there is nothing with `java` (https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/48607a8fdb1bece71a248c878e45203b).

Comment: @TobiasHermann are you looking at limits as imposed for the process running in the container? It's strange if `pgrep java` doesn't find anything. Can you manually find the process ID of your app running in the container and check it?

Comment: I looked at your graphs again (btw. would be great if you could summarize them in the description). It seems that your container has a memory limit of 4 GB RAM. By creating 6K threads you are asking for a trouble. The default thread stack size is 1M which could already exceed the available memory (6000 * 1M = 6GB). And of course you need bunch of RAM for regular heap and other stuff.

Comment: Thanks. Here is the `/proc/[...]/limits` output using my process ID: https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/c6e38668b36f8eb97ff69e15a45cf635

Regarding the stack size, I forgot to mention, that I've switched to `-Xss256K` at some point. And I've also tried with much larger amounts of RAM, e.g., 24 GB, and still had the same problem. I'll add additional info like this to the question.